# Proving $\otimes_{i=1}^{i=n}\mathcal{B}_{X_{i}}=\mathcal{B}_{\Pi X_{i}}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, tensor-products

I am given the following exercise:

> Let $X_{\alpha}$ be a measureable space with $\sigma$-algebra
>   $M_{\alpha}$ , mark $X\triangleq{\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha\in
>  A}X_{\alpha}}$ and $\pi_{\alpha}:X\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ .
>
> define $\otimes_{\alpha\in A}M_{\alpha}$ as the $\sigma$-algebra that
>   is created from sets of form
>   $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}\left(E_{\alpha}\right)$ where $E_{\alpha}\in
>  M_{\alpha}$

Part 1 of the question asked to prove that if $A$ is countable then $\otimes_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}$
is created by sets of form ${\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}}$
where $E_{\alpha}\in M_{\alpha}$ .

Given a topological space $X$ denote the Borel's $\sigma$ -algebra
on $X$ by $\mathcal{B}_{X}$

Consider $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ metric spaces and define $X=X_{1}\times\dots \times X_{n}$

Now the question asks:

> a) Prove
>   $\otimes_{i=1}^{i=n}\mathcal{B}_{X_{i}}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{X}$.
>
> b) Assume each $X_{i}$ is separable and prove
>   $\otimes_{i=1}^{i=n}\mathcal{B}_{X_{i}}=\mathcal{B}_{X}$.

I am having some problems with this question, mainly because I don't
have a strong memory of what the product topology is exactly (I have
a definition near me and so I am trying to work with that).

For $a$ I want to start with some element of the form $\Pi_{\alpha}E_{\alpha}$and
prove that it is an element of $\mathcal{B}_{x}$ but to be honest,
I am not completely sure how $\mathcal{B}_{X}$ looks like - how does
the open set in $X$ look like and why something of the form $\Pi_{\alpha}E_{\alpha}$
(or $\pi^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$) is such a set.

After I understand $a$ I hope I will have an idea for $b$

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't think b) is true in general. For a simple counterexample, take $X=X_1=X_2$ an uncountable space with [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology). Then the Borel algebra will be the entire space in each space as well as the product, but the product algebra will not contain the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x) \vert x\in X\}$. For a Hausdorff counterexample, take for $X$ the Niemytzki plane, the problem will be much the same. You need to assume something more: either that $X_i$ are actually metrizable, or that they are second-countable, I guess.

Comment: @tomasz - yes, you are correct. thank you for nor noting, it was said that $X$ is a metric space and I didn't notice and thought it was just a topological sapce. sorry! I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give a sketch of proof (it's homework!) in the case $n=2$; it's not hardly adaptable to the general case.

a) For $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $B_i\in\mathcal{B}_{X_i}$, we have $\pi_i^{-1}(B_i)\in\mathcal B_X$, as $\pi_i\colon \mathcal B_X\to \mathcal B_{X_i}$ is assumed to be measurable. Now, to get the result, we use the fact that $\mathcal B_X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the sets of the form $\pi_i^{-1}(B_i), i\in\{1,2\}, B_i\in\mathcal B_{X_i}$.

b) We have to show that $\mathcal{B}_{X_1}\otimes \mathcal{B}_{X_2}$ contains the open subsets of $X_1\times X_2$. It's not hard to see it for open sets of the form $O_1\times O_2$, where $O_i$ is open in $X_i$. Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ sequences respectively dense in $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $O\subset X_1\times X_2$ open. Fix $(x_1,x_2)\in O$. We can find open sets $O_i$ such that $(x,y)\in O_1\times O_2\subset O$. If $X_i$ has a countable base of open sets, we are done.

If the space are assumed to be metric, then separability implies that $X_i$ has a countable basis of open sets. But it's not true in general, as tomasz pointed out. 
Note that separability is needed, otherwise take $X_1=X_2=$ a "big set" with discrete topology.

Comment: How do you derive the Lindelöf property? Actually, I doubt that separability is enough. For instance, if we take $X_1=X_2$ an uncountable space with particular point topology, then I think the Borel algebra will be the entire power set in the spaces as well as the product, but I doubt the product algebra will contain the diagonal of the product.

Comment: What do you mean by "particular point topology"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology

Comment: You are right, I assumed the spaces with a topology coming from a metric.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) note that the product topology on $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is generated by "open cubes", that is sets of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n U_i$ where each $U_i \subseteq X_i$ is open. As $n=2$ suffices by induction. Let now $U \subseteq X_1$ open and look at $\{V \subseteq X_2 \mid U \times V \in \mathcal B_X\}$. By the open, this contains all open sets. Now show it's a $\sigma$-algebra. Now let $V \in \mathcal B_{X_2}$ and consider $\{ U\subseteq X_1 \mid U \times V \in \mathcal B_X\}$. We know that this contains all open $U$. Now conclude.